# Wildcard Match Between Characters

Tags: python, regex, boolean, any

I'd like to have `bool` if a wildcard search is true. Specifically, if the following exist: `_<any number or char>_`.

Ideally I'd like to find an elegant pythonic way. For example, `any` returns true for exact matches. Is there an equivalent for wildcard?

```
>>> lst = ['cherry', 'pineapple_1', 'apple', '_olive', 'banana_split_1']
>>> any('_.' in elem for elem in lst)
False
>>> any('_' in elem for elem in lst)
True
>>> any('_*_' in elem for elem in lst)
False
```

To clarify, the second command should return `True` b/c of `'banana_split_1'` element containing a characters between two underscores.

Comment: You tagged this question with `regex`, which is an obvious solution; what problem do you have with using regular expressions?

Comment: @Prune, yes I assume the solution will include `re`, but I've hard time building the expression. Moreover, I want to see if there are other approaches similar to `any` in case of exact matches.

Comment: The key to those matches is `in`, not `any` ... and `re` is the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), it would probably be the fastest for such a simple pattern, too:

```
>>> lst = ['cherry', 'pineapple_1', 'apple', '_olive', 'banana_split_1']
>>> any(x.find('_', x.find('_') + 2) != -1 for x in lst)
True
```

**EDIT** - Explanation: It loops through every element of the `lst` and attempts to find an underscore that is followed by another underscore as long as there is at least one character between them. Consider unraveling it for a single case:

```
>>> test = 'banana_split_1'
>>> index = test.find('_')  # 6, the index of the first underscore
>>> index2 = test.find('_', index + 2)  # 12, the index of the next underscore
>>> index2 != -1
True
```

If there wasn't a second underscore (removed by 2 spaces to the right so it requires at least one character between) the `index2` would be -1 and the test in the above generator would fail.

This is, obviously, repeated for all entries until a match is found or `any()` returns `False`.

Comment: This works for the pattern "_?_" (single character between underscores), but not for the requested case, "_*_" (alphanumeric string), as in the example `banana_split_1`.

Comment: Can you please explain the solution?

Comment: @Prune - This works for any number of characters (>1) between two underscores.

Comment: @zwer: ah ... I mis-matched the parenthses and jumped to an invalid conclusion.  Glad I didn't down-vote!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for elem in list:
    if bool(re.search(expression, elem)):
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key item you need is an alphanumeric descriptor, such as `_[0-9A-Za-z]+_`

```
0-9  digits
A-Z  upper-case
a-z  lower-case
[]   any one of these characters
+    at least one repetition (disallows null string)
```

Surround that in underscores, and I believe that's your search pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. It can work. Would you use `search` or `match`?

Comment: I'm going to put my instructor hat on: look at a [tutorial in regex}(https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) and learn *all* (well, as much as you feel like absorbing today) of your basics.